# How to place navigation drawers header below statusbar?

Tags: android

I want my header of my Navigation drawer to be below the statusbar. When searching for solutions, every result is about how to place it under the status bar. I have of course tried to "reverse" theese solutions to place the header below. But it hasn't worked and I'm testing it on a `Samsung Galaxy S7 API 23`

Right now it looks like this:

**This is my layout containing DrawerLayout, NavigationView:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#00ffff"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">


  <include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_drawer_layout"
    layout="@layout/navdrawer_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/arion_darkgray"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navdrawer_header"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_drawer_selector"
    app:itemIconTint="#fff"
    app:itemTextColor="#fff"
    app:menu="@menu/navdrawer_menu"
    app:theme="@style/custom_navDrawer_style" />

 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Toolbar layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MyHorseActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/myhorse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/arion_darkblue">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/myhorse_toolbar_innerlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:paddingRight="70dp"
                android:text="My Horse"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:backgroundTint="#ff0000"
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_shape" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <include
        layout="@layout/divider_lightblue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    </include>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include
    android:id="@+id/activity"
    layout="@layout/myhorse_activity_" />
```

Much of this is auto generated by Android Studio after I created my NavigationDrawer Class from the wizard

Answer (score 1):

You have not put your `xml` fully so I don't know whats wrong with your `xml` but if you want your `navigation drawer` below `action bar` then put your `drawerlayout` below your `toolbar` as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!--Start of the Toolbar and its items -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></LinearLayout>

        <!--Used for displaying Navigation Drawer slide-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/navigation_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**According to your edited question drawerlayout xml would be like**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_drawer_layout"
        layout="@layout/navdrawer_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#00ffff"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/activity"
            layout="@layout/myhorse_activity_" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/arion_darkgray"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/navdrawer_header"
            app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_drawer_selector"
            app:itemIconTint="#fff"
            app:itemTextColor="#fff"
            app:menu="@menu/navdrawer_menu"
            app:theme="@style/custom_navDrawer_style" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**and toolbar layout will be like**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MyHorseActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/myhorse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/arion_darkblue">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/myhorse_toolbar_innerlayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:paddingRight="70dp"
                    android:text="My Horse"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="15dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
                    android:backgroundTint="#ff0000" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <include
            layout="@layout/divider_lightblue"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I agree with indramurari. with out looking at all the xml code can not tell breaking point exactly. how ever try to use Linear Layout as   indramurari mentioned

Comment: @Umanda It was an syntax error, now you can see the whole code

Comment: Its not working. My NavigationView is not visible when I click on the menu button.

Answer (score 0):

I used the xml file below to achieve what you asked. But this way, the drawer opens below both the "status bar" and the "toolbar"

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:elevation="5dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id = "@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:id = "@+id/drawerList"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:elevation="5dp"></ListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Look again the question. I just edited with all the relevant code

Comment: i believe indramurari answered your question . You just need to use linear layout as your parent tag. and use toolbar and drawer layout within it !

Comment: Its not working. My NavigationView is not visible when I click on the menu button.

Comment: then use the xml code which i have provided above . The listview is the navigation view here which opens from the left. Populate this ListView from your Activity and it should work fine .